# Python dfply: unable to mask on multiple conditions

Tags: python, logical-operators, dfply

I am an R user learning how to use Python's `dfply`, the Python equivalent to R's `dplyr`. My problem: in dfply, I am unable to mask on multiple conditions in a pipe. I seek a solution involving dfply pipes rather than multiple lines of subsetting.

My code:

```
# Import
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dfply import *

# Create data frame and mask it
df  = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,np.nan],'c':[5,4,3,2,1]})
df2 = (df >>
        mask((X.a.isnull()) | ~(X.b.isnull())))
print(df)
print(df2)
```

Here is the oringal data frame, df:

```
       a    b    c
    0  NaN  6.0  5
    1  2.0  7.0  4
    2  3.0  8.0  3
    3  4.0  9.0  2
    4  5.0  NaN  1
```

And here is the result of the piped mask, df2:

```
         a    b    c
      0  NaN  6.0  5
      4  5.0  NaN  1
```

However, I expect this instead:

```
         a    b    c
      0  NaN  6.0  5
      1  2.0  7.0  4
      2  3.0  8.0  3
      3  4.0  9.0  2
```

Why don't the "|" and "~" operators result in rows in which column "a" is *either* NaN or column "b" is **not** NaN?

By the way, I also tried `np.logical_or()`:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,np.nan],'c':[5,4,3,2,1]})
df2 = (df >>
        mask(np.logical_or(X.a.isnull(),~X.b.isnull())))
print(df)
print(df2)
```

But this resulted in error:

```
mask(np.logical_or(X.a.isnull(),~X.b.isnull())))
ValueError: invalid __array_struct__
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Tweak the second conditional to "df.col2.notnull()". No idea why the tilde is ignored after the pipe.

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.nan,2,3,4,5],'b':[6,7,8,9,np.nan],'c':[5,4,3,2,1]})
df2 = (df >> mask((X.a.isnull()) | (X.b.notnull())))

print(df2)

     a    b  c
0  NaN  6.0  5
1  2.0  7.0  4
2  3.0  8.0  3
3  4.0  9.0  2
```

Comment: Can you please explain your answer?

Comment: Thank you very much CurlyW. That works. But do you know why this original logic doesn't work...:

`df2 = (df >>
        mask((X.a.isnull()) | ~(X.b.isnull())))`

...? It seems `dfply` ignores the `~` after `|`. I'd like to be confident that I can apply standard boolean operators in a dfply mask, since the equivalent of notnull() may not always exist. 

By the way, I tried `or`, but this resulted in an error.

Answer (score 0):

How about `filter_by`?

```
df >> filter_by((X.a.isnull()) | (X.b.isnull()))
```

Comment: Hi @loveactualry. The challenge here is that dfply isn't recognising the ~ on the right side of the OR (|) in my original code. 

In your suggestion, when I change (X.b.isnull())) to ~(X.b.isnull())) I still get a result of:

     a    b  c
0  NaN  6.0  5
4  5.0  NaN  1

...which is not what I expect. Rather, I expect: 

         a    b    c
      0  NaN  6.0  5
      1  2.0  7.0  4
      2  3.0  8.0  3
      3  4.0  9.0  2

Comment: Oh, sorry... I'll try to do again.